# Passing variable to modal as <span>, then needing to use the resolved variable in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

am grateful for any and all help here please.

I'm passing a data-id value to a bootstrap modal form. The data-id is generated from a while loop. Here is the line from within the loop...

```
echo "<div class='col-2'><a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaleditprice' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' data-id='".$bids['PriceID']."'><i class='far fa-edit'></i></a></div>";
```

Then I have some jquery which sends the data to the modal form...

```
$('#modaleditprice').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
var SentPriceID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
$(this).find('.ModalPriceID').text(SentPriceID);
});
```

Finally, here is the php and html code within the modal form itself...

```
$PriceID = "<span class='ModalPriceID'></span>";
$priceSQL = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE PriceID = ".$PriceID;
$priceQRY = $conn->query($priceSQL);
```

...

```
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Edit Price - <?php echo $PriceID; ?></h4>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
</button>
</div>

 <div class="modal-body">
 <form method="POST" action="editprice.php">
 etc...
```

The form is populated with the values retrieved from the SQL query. The form works fine if I can get the SQL query to work... The issue is that I cannot parse the query above successfully within the php segment. The html segment renders the correct value of $PriceID i.e. it first renders as the span code, which then shows the correct price ID value once the html is completed loading. But I need to use this as a resolved variable beforehand. Any ideas?

edited: I'm using two php files which may be the problem here i.e. I include the modal file based on a condition in my main file...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['UserRole']) && ($_SESSION['UserRole'] == 'Trader' || $_SESSION['UserRole'] == 'Viewer'))   {
// Proceed if Viewer or Trader else boot out
include_once '../../'.$config["paths"]["secured"].'pricemodals.php';
```

Comment: **var SentPriceID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');** Just use this variable to send to PHP, instead of HTML code.

Comment: That results in an undefined variable error. I'm assuming it's because the php within the modal file is separate to the php in the original file i.e. I'm using a conditional include to bring in the modal file...

Comment: Can you also post the html form you're using please?

Comment: I've edited to show where I start the form. The form works fine when the SQL query works but problem is that the query fails as the string has not resolved yet i.e. before the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sql statement will resolve to the following

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE PriceID = <span class='ModalPriceID'></span>;
```

since you are string to $PriceID and not a reference. It also looks like you are attempting to do actions on the page within the php after the page is rendered. You will need to either create a small form within the modal that sends the values as form data eg $_POST/$_GET where the page will essentially refresh and process those items on the top of the page if they exist,
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

or better yet use AJAX to send the query asynchronously and react to the response without a page load. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: Yup, that's correct. The string resolves to the correct value in the html but not in the php. Will get onto AJAX asap then. Thanks... Any pointers on what AJAX methods I should be focusing on?